# Rails Autocomplete (depending on the choice)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, coffeescript

I have this:

```
# _form.html.erb
f.text_field :c,  data: {autocomplete_source: @correlations.all.map { |x| x.name }}<br>
f.text_field :n,  data: {autocomplete_source: @customers.all.map { |x| x.note}}

// Coffee script
$('#launch_c').autocomplete source: $('#launch_c').data('autocomplete-source')
$('#launch_n').autocomplete source: $('#launch_n').data('autocomplete-source')
```

I need that the variable @customers depending on the choice of correlation...
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is fairly vague as to what you are attempting to do or what the issue is. I highly recommend reading through these as pages:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer they are both fantastic resources to use when asking or answering questions and will help you get the best answers quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this isn't trivial to do. Basically you'll need something like this:

- Store all Customers in nested JSON on the page, so that Jquery can easily look up all the Customers for a given Correlation. (If there are more than a hundredish Customers or Correlations, you may want an AJAX call instead of pre-loading all the possible records into the page.)
- Jquery code that detects when a Correlation is selected, fetches the Customers array for that Correlation, and re-initializes the Customer autocomplete widget with the relevant data. See the [Jquery Autocomplete API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change) for more detail on how to detect change events etc.

The result might look something like this Jquery code:

```
$('#launch_c').autocomplete({
  source: $('#launch_c').data('autocomplete-source'),
  change: function(event, ui){
    var correlation_name = ui.item.value;
    var data = $('#launch_n').data('autocomplete-source')[correlation_name];
    $('#launch_n').autocomplete({ source: data });
  }
});
```

And it would require #launch_n to have a `data-autocomplete-source` nested JSON something like this:

```
{
  "correlation1_name": ["customer1_name", "customer2_name", "customer3_name"],
  "correlation2_name": ["customer4_name", "customer5_name", "customer6_name"],
  "correlation3_name": ["customer7_name", "customer8_name", "customer9_name"],
  // etc.
}
```